# Accessing prefix of config list elements to get value from dictionary

Tags: python, bioinformatics, snakemake, vcf-variant-call-format

So i'm trying to build a pipeline using snakemake and i have a bit of an issue to access the values in the dictionary "small_reference" in the config file.
Depending on the sample, I want to use a different reference for the alignment.

Config file:

```
samples: ['C130165', 'C014044p', 'C130166', 'C130157', 'C014040p', 'C014054b-1', 'C051198-A', 'C014042p', 'C052007W-C', 'C130167', 'C051198-B', 'C130157A', 'C130165A', 'C014038p', 'C052004-B', 'C051198-C', 'C052004-C', 'C130167', 'C052003-B', 'C130165', 'C052003-A', 'C052004-A', 'C052002-C', 'C130157', 'C052005-C', 'C130157W', 'C130167A', 'C130157A', 'C130166A', 'C052002-A', 'C130157N', 'C052006-B', 'C014063pW', 'C130157W', 'C130157N', 'C014054b-2', 'C052002-B', 'C130167A', 'C052006-C', 'C130166A', 'C052007W-B', 'C052003-C', 'C130165A', 'C014064bW', 'C052005-B', 'C130166', 'C052006-A', 'C052005-A']


reference: "/mnt/storage/refs/human_1kg/human_g1k_v37.fasta"

index: "/mnt/storage/refs/human_1kg/human_g1k_v37.fasta.fai"

dbsnp: "/mnt/storage/refs/human_1kg/dbsnp_137.b37.vcf"

small_reference: {
    C01: "/mnt/storage/projects/hiv_data/refs/BRCA/BRCA12_PALB2.fasta",
    Z01: "/mnt/storage/projects/hiv_data/refs/BRCA/BRCA12.fasta",
    C02: "/mnt/storage/projects/hiv_data/refs/STICKLERS/STICKERS_ext.fasta",
    C03: "/mnt/storage/projects/hiv_data/refs/TS/TS.fasta",
    C04: "/mnt/storage/projects/hiv_data/refs/STICKLERS/STICKERS.fasta",
    C05: "/mnt/storage/projects/hiv_data/refs/PKD_GANAB/PKD.fasta",
    C07: "/mnt/storage/projects/hiv_data/refs/NEMO/NEMO.fasta",
    C08: "/mnt/storage/projects/hiv_data/refs/HNPCC/HNPCC.fasta",
    C09: "/mnt/storage/projects/hiv_data/refs/TAU/TAU.fasta",
    C10: "/mnt/storage/projects/hiv_data/refs/THYROID/THYROID.fasta",
    C12: "/mnt/storage/projects/hiv_data/refs/VWF/VWF.fasta",
    C13: "/mnt/storage/refs/human_1kg/human_g1k_v37.fasta",
    C17: "/mnt/storage/projects/hiv_data/refs/DICER_PALB2/DICER_PALB2.fasta",
    C18: "/mnt/storage/projects/hiv_data/refs/DICER_PALB2/DICER_PALB2.fasta",
}

baits: {
    C01: "/mnt/storage/projects/hiv_data/refs/BRCA/BRCA12_PALB2.bed",
    Z01: "/mnt/storage/projects/hiv_data/refs/BRCA/BRCA12_exons.bed",
    C02: "/mnt/storage/projects/hiv_data/refs/STICKLERS/STICKERS_ext.bed",
    C03: "/mnt/storage/projects/hiv_data/refs/TS/TS_exons.bed",
    C04: "/mnt/storage/projects/hiv_data/refs/STICKLERS/STICKERS.bed",
    C05: "/mnt/storage/projects/hiv_data/refs/PKD_GANAB/PKD.bed",
    C07: "/mnt/storage/projects/hiv_data/refs/NEMO/NEMO.bed",
    C08: "/mnt/storage/projects/hiv_data/refs/HNPCC/HNPCC.bed",
    C09: "/mnt/storage/projects/hiv_data/refs/TAU/TAU.bed",
    C10: "/mnt/storage/projects/hiv_data/refs/THYROID/THYROID_v2.bed",
    C12: "/mnt/storage/projects/hiv_data/refs/VWF/VWF.bed",
    C13: "/mnt/storage/refs/human_1kg/human_g1k_v37.bed",
    C17: "/mnt/storage/projects/hiv_data/refs/DICER_PALB2/DICER_PALB2.bed",
    C18: "/mnt/storage/projects/hiv_data/refs/DICER_PALB2/DICER_PALB2.bed",
}
```

Depending of the first 3 characters of the sample, i want to choose a different reference. I wrote a function that could do the trick when config["samples"] was just a string. But now i want to consider runfolders so i have a list of samples.

Working function:

```
def get_ref(wildcards):
    prefix = config["samples"][0:3]
    return config["small_reference"][prefix]
```

I first got this error `Duplicate output file pattern in rule` when i just changed the config file (so when running the full pipeline)

Test rule:

```
rule test:
    input:
        fq = expand("{sample}.1.fq.gz", sample = config["samples"]),
        ref = get_ref
    shell:
        "echo {input.fq} {input.ref}"
```

Now i have this error when running the test rule:

```
InputFunctionException in line 17 of /mnt/storage/home/kimy/projects/automate_CP/scripts/Snakefile:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
Wildcards:
```

Example: C014038p --> C01 --> /mnt/storage/projects/hiv_data/refs/BRCA/BRCA12_PALB2.fasta

How can I get the correct "small_reference" according to the prefix of the sample being analyzed by the pipeline?

Comment: prefixes = [a[0:3] for a in config["samples"]]

Comment: I don't think that helps me. I edited my question so it is clearer, my end goal is to get the correct "small_reference" according to the prefix of the sample being analyzed by the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i had snakemake all wrong, expand() is used to create the wildcards --> specify it only in rule all not in every rule.
Modified function that works:

```
def get_ref(wildcards):
    prefix = wildcards.sample[0:3]
    return config["small_reference"][prefix]
```

Comment: `expand()` is used to create lists, and that's all. `wildcards` can be seen as "variables". As snakemake is based on files (inputs and outputs) those "variables" have to be defined somewhere. This somewhere is usually the rule all (first rule defined in snakefile) since snakemake will first have a look at the target files it must create, then go down through the rules to see how to create those targets.